# Spark SQL DataFrame pretty print

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm not very good with Scala (I'm more an R addict) I wish to display the WrappedArray elemnt's content (see below  `sqlDf.show()`) in two rows using Scala in `spark-shell`. I've tried the `explode()` function but couldn't get further ...

```
scala> val sqlDf = spark.sql("select t.articles.donneesComptablesArticle.taxes from  dau_temp t")
sqlDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [taxes: array<array<struct<baseImposition:bigint,codeCommunautaire:string,codeNatureTaxe:string,codeTaxe:string,droitCautionnable:boolean,droitPercu:boolean,imputationCreditCautionne:boolean,montantLiquidation:bigint,quotite:double,statutAi2:boolean,statutDeLiquidation:string,statutRessourcesPropres:boolean,typeTaxe:string>>>]

scala> sqlDf.show
16/12/21 15:13:21 WARN util.Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
+--------------------+
|               taxes|
+--------------------+
|[WrappedArray([12...|
+--------------------+


scala> sqlDf.printSchema
root
 |-- taxes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- baseImposition: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- codeCommunautaire: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- codeNatureTaxe: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- codeTaxe: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- droitCautionnable: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- droitPercu: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- imputationCreditCautionne: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- montantLiquidation: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- quotite: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- statutAi2: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- statutDeLiquidation: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- statutRessourcesPropres: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- typeTaxe: string (nullable = true)

scala> val sqlDfTaxes = sqlDf.select(explode(sqlDf("taxes")))
sqlDfTaxes: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col: array<struct<baseImposition:bigint,codeCommunautaire:string,codeNatureTaxe:string,codeTaxe:string,droitCautionnable:boolean,droitPercu:boolean,imputationCreditCautionne:boolean,montantLiquidation:bigint,quotite:double,statutAi2:boolean,statutDeLiquidation:string,statutRessourcesPropres:boolean,typeTaxe:string>>]

scala> sqlDfTaxes.show()
16/12/21 15:22:28 WARN util.Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
+--------------------+
|                 col|
+--------------------+
|[[12564,B00,TVA,A...|
+--------------------+
```

The "readable" content looks like this (**THIS IS MY GOA**L: a classic row x columns structure display with headers):

```
codeTaxe codeCommunautaire baseImposition quotite montantLiquidation statutDeLiquidation
A445               B00          12564    20.0               2513                   C
U165               A00          12000     4.7                564                   C
codeNatureTaxe typeTaxe statutRessourcesPropres statutAi2 imputationCreditCautionne
TVA    ADVAL                   FALSE      TRUE                     FALSE
DD    ADVAL                    TRUE     FALSE                      TRUE
droitCautionnable droitPercu
FALSE       TRUE
FALSE       TRUE
```

and the class of each row is (found it using R package `sparklyr`):

```
<jobj[100]>
  class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
  [12564,B00,TVA,A445,false,true,false,2513,20.0,true,C,false,ADVAL]

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
<jobj[101]>
  class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
  [12000,A00,DD,U165,false,true,true,564,4.7,false,C,true,ADVAL]
```

Comment: `sqlDf.show(truncate = false)` would be a good place to start...

Comment: @Tzach Zohar: thank you! you've indeed answered my "print pretty" question. Now, what I've really meant ;-)  was to obtain a classic "rows x columns" structure with the headers (like in my "readable" content above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can explode on each column:

```
val flattenedtaxes = sqlDf.withColumn("codeCommunautaire",  org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode($"taxes. codeCommunautaire"))
```

After this your `flattenedtaxes` will have 2 columns taxes(all the columns as is)  new column `codeCommunautaire`

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, I got the following error: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`taxes`['codeCommunautaire']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''codeCommunautaire'' is of string type.` I will keep investigating, but if you have a quick solution please don't hesitate !

Comment: I can send you the (dummy) JSON file as well, thanks.

Comment: please send so that i can look into it give you working code

Comment: As you said this is a json file, you can do one thing write your `sqlDf` to some location. then read the file with json formatter `val df = sqlContext.read.json("yourpathof/sqlDf")` then just print `df.show`